# Android startForegroundService/startService is not actually launching the Intent/Service?

Tags: android

In my main Activity I call a function in a helper class, that function:

```
public void initForegroundService(Activity activity) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(activity, MyForegroundService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(INTENT_CHANNEL_ID, "channelID");
    serviceIntent.putExtra(INTENT_CHANNEL_NAME, "channelName");
    serviceIntent.putExtra(INTENT_TITLE, "title");
    serviceIntent.putExtra(INTENT_TEXT, "text");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        System.out.println("doing first one");
        activity.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
    } else {
        System.out.println("doing second one");
        activity.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

Either of the print states *do* print out, so either `activity.startForegroundService()` is called or `activity.startService` is called.

In my MyForegroundService.java:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    System.out.println("Hello world!"); // THIS NEVER IS PRINTED, onStartCommand() NEVER IS CALLED

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, null);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelID,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, channelID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sn_service_notif)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    } else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sn_service_notif)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(false);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

That print statement above is never called. The Service object is never created or at least never started?

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add your service to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".MyForegroundService" />
```

And also about `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: I had the permission, forgot about the service declaration. It's always the Manifest...lol. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It might be nice to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running).

> Support for long-running workers ...These Workers can run longer than 10 minutes. Example use-cases for this new feature include bulk uploads or downloads (that cannot be chunked), crunching on an ML model locally, or a task that's important to the user of the app.

[Simple example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running-kotlin) of a long running worker that downloads a file.